# Append dataframe returns empty dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have around 400 tables that I want to merge based on some specific columns (some tables **may not have all columns** compared to `column_list` - then there should be `NaN`)

I am using the code below. It filters the columns of interest like intended but when appending `filter_df` to `final`, then `final` stays empty. Any help much appreciated.

```
final = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_list)

files = os.listdir(path)
num = len(files)

for idx, file in enumerate(files):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file), sep=',', index_col=False, header=3)
    df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip()) # Some Column Names have trailing space
    filter_df = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(column_list)]

    final.append(filter_df, ignore_index=True)
    print('Progress:',round((idx+1)/num,4)*100, '%')

pd.DataFrame.to_csv(final, base_path + 'Master_File.csv')
```

Comment: `append` is not an in-place operation. Change to `final = final.append(filter_df, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

try to set final to append result, like this

```
final = final.append(filter_df, ignore_index=True)
```